# Android split a string when same character come together

Tags: java, android, split

Hi I need to split a character into two in Android

Suppose the string is

```
stat = "Haihow@areyou"
```

I know how to split this character,

```
String[] toks      = stat.split("@");

                tok1        = toks[0];
                tok2        = toks[1];
```

But what I need is I need to split only when two @ symbol come together

that means "Hai@how@@areyou'

should get result 'Hai@how' and 'areyou'. For that what change I need to do in the above code.

Comment: `stat.split("@{2}");` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] toks  = stat.split("@@");

                tok1        = toks[0];
                tok2        = toks[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This one looks simple. What about using that as your split string? Have you tried this?

```
String[] toks = stat.split("@@");
```

Answer (score 1):

just put  `String[] toks  =stat.split("@@");`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :
using pattern :

```
stat.split(Pattern.quote("@@"));
```